# Passing Login credentials into UIWebView

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I have an in-app login page that gets an SID. How would I pass these login credentials into a displayed UIWebView in Swift?

EDIT: I was thinking I would just be able to load the URL into my webview with the SID in the web address, but I am getting an error doing this.

Comment: What error are you getting? Also, when you say "with the SID in the web address", how are you placing it in the web address?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Presumably you're displaying a website (e.g., www.foo.com) in the `UIWebView` and want to pass the SID to the `UIWebView` to login to www.foo.com.

You'll want to set up an `NSMutableURLRequest` with `HTMLBody` and `HTTPMethod` set properly to achieve this. The way to pass the SID to login is via a query parameter.

```
var url = NSURL(string: "http://www.foo.com")

var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)

// usually to login you send a POST with the user's credentials
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

// this is where you would assign the SID (from a UITextView, etc.)
var sid = "1234" // getSid()

var bodyData = "SID=\(sid)"

// encode the query params as UTF8
request.HTTPBody = bodyData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

// this will load the UIWebView by sending the POST with the query string:
// http://www.foo.com/?SID=1234
webView.loadRequest(request)
```